# Would it enhance performance to assign a DOM element to a global variable if its used in a lot of functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's being suggested in my workspace that maybe we can enhance performance of our JQuery if we save an element to a variable so JQ doesnt have to search the DOM everytime we call it.

For instance... say I use `$('#myPopUp')` in quite a few functions throughout our javascript,  the suggestion is that in the `document.ready` function I save it to a variable ...

`mypopup = $('#myPopUp')` and then use this `$(mypopup).hide()`, `.show()`, `blah()` throughout the script.

Will this increase our performance or is it not worth it to add more variables to the global namespace?

Comment: I can't find the video or article that I saw it in, but the case they made was that variables will be fastest (most of the time) if they are private to the function that uses them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be global unless you're using it in two different .js files.

Comment: @KevinB even then it wouldn't need to be global if you use a good pattern for your JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would increase the performance, if you use it correctly (which you don't so far).

The big point in caching a *jQuery collection* is

- don't query the DOM every time
- don't call the jQuery constructor all the time

You don't need to wrap your cached variable in `$()`, just access it like

```
mypopup.hide();
```

---

One word of attention: You're using the term *global variable*, which you still shouldn't do at all. Its just enough to create your own *application context* / *-namepsace* and keep such variables "global" within there. You don't want to clobber the actual global context.

Comment: thanks for that clarification on the $(varName).hide() as opposed to the varname.hide().
I think I am also misusing the 'global' term ... I mean global as in available to the whole (but single) script they are in - basically variables that I have declared outside of all functions so that if I were to call this variable later on inside numerous functions, they will all have a reference to it ... I should call this something different?  And does this change my question?

Comment: @toddv: it wouldn't change the question no, its just a question of 'being nice to other scripts, possibly loaded on your site'. Its always a good idea never to pollute the global context with anything to avoid conflicts and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Saving jQuery elements to a variable is definitely more performant than repeatedly passing the selector. *How much faster* is questionable, depending on your selectors and the complexity of the DOM. It's possible that it's only negligibly faster, but saving to a variable is still a best practice. In addition to faster execution, code minification tools can rename the variable to something short like `a`, which saves bytes and makes the physical load time of the JS file faster.

However, your example misuses this technique.

```
mypopup = $('#myPopUp');
$(mypopup).hide();
```

You're saving the jQuery object to the variable `mypopup` but you're passing that back into the jQuery constructor on the second line. Since it's already a jQuery object, you can call methods on it directly:

```
mypopup.hide();
```

By convention you should indicate that your variable is a jQuery object by preceding the variable name with a dollar sign, like so: `$mypopup`.